# NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential does not help. How to make iOS trust my server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, nsurlsession

My server uses self signed SSL certificates. And iOS does not want to accept them no matter what I do. This is my code:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
 didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition,
                         NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler
{
NSString* authenticationMethod = challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod;

if (![authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
{
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling, nil);
    return;
}

SecTrustRef trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;

CFIndex count = SecTrustGetCertificateCount(trust);
CFMutableArrayRef originalCertificates = CFArrayCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);

for (CFIndex i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    SecCertificateRef certRef = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(trust, i);
    CFArrayAppendValue(originalCertificates, certRef);
    CFStringRef certSummary = SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary(certRef);
    NSLog(@"CERT %ld %@", i, certSummary);
}

//SecPolicyRef policyRef = SecPolicyCreateSSL(true, CFSTR("192.168.50.80"));
SecPolicyRef policyRef = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();
SecTrustRef newTrust;

OSStatus status = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(originalCertificates, policyRef, & newTrust);

assert(status == noErr);

NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"no1bcCA" ofType:@"der"];
NSData* data   = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (CFDataRef) data);

assert(cert);

NSString* rootPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"no1bcRootCA" ofType:@"der"];
NSData* rootData   = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:rootPath];

SecCertificateRef rootCert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (CFDataRef) rootData);
assert(rootCert);

SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(newTrust, (CFArrayRef)@[(__bridge id)rootCert, (__bridge id)cert]);
SecTrustSetAnchorCertificatesOnly(newTrust, NO);

SecTrustResultType trustResult;

SecTrustEvaluate(newTrust, &trustResult);

if (trustResult == kSecTrustResultUnspecified || trustResult == kSecTrustResultProceed)
{
    NSURLCredential* credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:newTrust];
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, credential);

}
else
{

 completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling, nil);
}
}
```

so `trustResult` is `kSecTrustResultUnspecified` but in the completion handler of my `NSURLSessionDataTask` I still receive the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x6000003040b0>, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(
"<cert(0x7f81ef80ca00) s: sems.no1bc.local i: no1bcCA>",
"<cert(0x7f81ef80d400) s: no1bcCA i: no1bcRootCA>",
"<cert(0x7f81ef82b800) s: no1bcRootCA i: no1bcRootCA>"
), NSUnderlyingError=0x604000255030 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x6000003040b0>, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9802, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=(
"<cert(0x7f81ef80ca00) s: sems.no1bc.local i: no1bcCA>",
"<cert(0x7f81ef80d400) s: no1bcCA i: no1bcRootCA>",
"<cert(0x7f81ef82b800) s: no1bcRootCA i: no1bcRootCA>"
)}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://192.168.50.80/pgpuniversaldesktop, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://192.168.50.80/pgpuniversaldesktop, NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0}
```

I love the recovery suggestion. It says

> Would you like to connect to the server anyway?

Yes, I would, but how? What do I do?

Apart from all that I also tried to play with ATS, this is what I put into the plist file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>192.168.50.80</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

but it never helps. So, I explicitly tell iOS: "Trust this server, trust it", but it doesn't. What may be the reason? How do I force the system to trust the server? And how am I supposed to connect to the server anyway?

It is funny that it works without problems if I run this code from a Mac app. But doesn't work on iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the server ran some outdated TLS. Mac was able to deal with it whereas iOS not, so it never allowed to connect to the server no matter what. The solution was to fix the server

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 11, apparently you need to also set `NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy` to `false` for that domain.  Otherwise, App Transport Security won't even let your custom cert reach your custom authentication code.  This is arguably a bug.

For more info, see [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/80638) in Apple's developer forums.